# Using a formulla through mysql queries: error

Tags: php, mysql

I have created a database of kittens where I need to use the following formula.  In this regard I have two tables: birth and disposal.

```
Birth table contains id, dob, owner, date of purchase

disposal table contains id, date of disposal (dodisposal), cause of death, sold, treatment
```

I am now trying use a formula for the two table using the following MySQL query but it is not working.

```
Select birth.owner, (((select count(disposal.id) from disposal WHERE
   dodisposal BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 600 DAY) AND NOW()) /
     (select count(birth.id) from birth where birth.id not in 
         (select disposal.id from disposal)
     )
   ) * 100) 
from birth left join disposal on
disposal.brandnumber = birth.id group by birth.owner
```

but I keep getting same results for all owners:

ie

```
rita   : 79.6
sunita : 79.6
Smith  : 79.6
```

The result I am expecting should be through the following formula:

```
Number of deaths in the current year / total number of live cats * 100
```

Comment: select birth.id from birth where dodisposal not in (select disposal.id from disposal) this query will return more than one that's why you are getting that error. If you want anyone row then change that subquery to like select birth.id from birth where dodisposal not in (select disposal.id from disposal) limit 1

Comment: dear @Gaj  I have edited my question to make it more clear.  I want a list generated which gives me the mortality rate per owner . Something like rita : 2, sunita : 1.9 etc but I am unable to do that. Please help

Comment: check your on clause and the subquery where clause. It seems contradict. In ON CLAUSE you are using "on disposal.brandnumber = birth.id " but in the where clause you are checking "birth.id not in (select disposal.id from disposal)". If you couldn't correct the mistake then post the full structure of both tables and few sample data

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this problem by making two separate views and then their results using a MySQL query.

```
create view cats as select id, count(disposal.id) from disposal WHERE
   dodisposal BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 600 DAY) AND NOW()) as dead


create view livecates as select count(birth.id) from birth left join disposal on disposal.id = birth.id where birth.id not in (select disposal.id from disposal) as live


select livecats.id, (dead/live * 100) from livecats left join cats on livecats.id = cats.id group by livecats.id
```